# Peak hold circuit with LM6132 is not working

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics

I am trying to make a peak hold circuit using LM6132 op amps. Below is the schematic:

[image]

The input (green) and output (red) waveforms are as below:

[image]

The red line should be following the green line until green peak is reached, and after the pulse peak is detected, the red line should stay at the maximum level regardless of the following pulse.

Can anybody spot what is wrong with my circuit?

Comment: Why have you put those 52.3k resistors in series with your opamps' power supplies?

Comment: - and you're missing a connection between the output of U2 and its inverting input (the feedback wire is only connected to R5).

Comment: Why don't you use a "conditional" track/hold?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to do it with LM6161, with "some" modifications of the initial OP picture.
NB: not rail to rail opamp (?), so dual supplies.
Important (?):  "Stable with unlimited capacitive load", see [LM6161](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/33083.pdf).

With a slow input (period 10 ms)...
R9 & R10 for Vd compensation.

[image]

With a faster input (period 1 ms)...

[image]